# Paperclip and nearly a dozen different files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have an `Apps` model, and each App will have up to 10 separate files associated with it.

- 1 - Large icon
- 1 - Small icon
- 4 - iPhone screenshots
- 4 - iPad screenshots

Is there a better way to setup the associated Paperclip columns than adding the required 4 columns for EACH image (meaning 40 new columns added to my `Apps` model)?

For clarification, it's not that there are just 10 random images associated with each App. There are 4 distinct *types* of images for each app, which could total up to 10 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a model named AppImages, that belongs_to App.

Example App Image:

- id
- size: string (large | small | iphone | ipad)
- belongs_to: app_id
- image_"paperclip columns"

This method will also allow you to easily expand the "type" of photos belonging to your app without doing any migrations.